# Failed to connect from android devcie to bluetooth dongle IOGEAR GBS301 200f(slave)

Tags: bluetooth

### Failed to connect IOGEAR GBS301 200f exception: service discovery failed

- dongle in slave and connected to VSM device i can discover and pair dongle successfully
- but can not able to connect
- am using android api 10
- kindly help me thanks in advance

discovery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;
            try {

                socket = mBluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(Custom.MY_UUID);
                Method m = mBluetoothDevice.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord", new Class[] {UUID.class});
                socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mBluetoothDevice, Custom.MY_UUID);
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                socket.connect();

                Custom.showToast(context, "Conneted.");

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem using node.js noble/bleno. My service can be discovered if I use a [Plugable](http://plugable.com/products/usb-bt4le) dongle, but discovery fail on Android and bleno if I use the [IOGear](http://www.iogear.com/product/GBU521/) dongle. I reproduced the issue on 2 different machines with different Linux version. If I use an iPhone for discovery it works.

Something seems broken between the IOGear dongle BT stack and Android/noble implementation.
It is weird because they use the same Broadcom BCM20702 chipset.